# Break line into 100m segments

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have a line geometry in PostGIS and I am wondering how I would break the line into 100m segments. Is there a function for this?

Comment: One option would be to use `ST_Segmentize`, some examples can be found here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334020/using-st-segmentize-to-postgresql-table-of-segments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the linear referencing functions http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#Linear_Referencing

ST_LineSubstring is probably the one that you want to use http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Line_Substring.html

Before using ST_Line_Substring you must query the total length of the linestring and build SQL that calculates a fraction that corresponds with 100 m.

Comment: There's a really good example in the ST_LineSubstring documentation that uses the PostgreSQL generate_series() to cut linestrings into 100 unit segments - https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html.

Answer (score 8):

The example in the PostGIS [ST_LineSubstring](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html) doc is a bit dated.  Modern Postgres has the `JOIN LATERAL` feature, which allows for more compact and efficient SQL.  Here's a simple example:

```
WITH
data AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ( 'A', 'LINESTRING( 0 0, 200 0)'::geometry ),
        ( 'B', 'LINESTRING( 0 100, 350 100)'::geometry ),
        ( 'C', 'LINESTRING( 0 200, 50 200)'::geometry )
    ) AS t(id, geom)
)
SELECT ST_LineSubstring( d.geom, substart, 
    CASE WHEN subend > 1 THEN 1 ELSE subend END ) geom
FROM (SELECT id, geom, ST_Length(geom) len, 100 sublen FROM data) AS d
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT i,  
            (sublen * i)/len AS substart,
            (sublen * (i+1)) / len AS subend
        FROM generate_series(0, 
            floor( d.len / sublen )::integer ) AS t(i)
        WHERE (sublen * i)/len <> 1.0  
    ) AS d2;
```

Comment: Very nice; works perfectly.