# Using ST_Segmentize to PostgreSQL table of segments?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a PostgreSQL table with straight lines (segments) that I need to subdivide in further segments so that none of them is more than 50 metres long. I am new using PostGIS (and SQL) and I'm struggling quite a bit to understand 'ST_xxxx' commands in general. The examples I see in the documentation are way too simple. Like the following one:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(
ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-29 -27,-30 -29.7,-36 -31,-45 -33),(-45 -33,-46 32))'),5)
);
```

How can I apply ST_Segmentize (and later on ST_AsText) to the geometry of my table of segments? I can obviously obtain all the geometries of the segments with a simple query (`SELECT geom from public.segments`). But then, how should I insert the result of this query into the code shown above?

Something like this does not work:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(
ST_GeomFromText(SELECT geom from public.segments),50)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `SELECT` a column `FROM` a table, the column value(s) are made available to functions, either per row, or as aggregates. Function results can be passed consecutively into enclosing functions.

In this case you would simply

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(geom::GEOGRAPHY, 50)) AS geom
FROM   public.segments
;
```

Note that I use a cast (`::`) to `GEOGRAPHY`; since you intent to use *meter* as distance threshold, you either need your geometries projected in a suitable CRS (with *meter* as unit), or the `GEOGRAPHY` type, which implicitly uses *meter* as unit; this **only works on geographic reference systems**, and the cast assumes EPSG:4326 (WGS84) as the default.

---

**However**:

`ST_Segmentize` only **inserts vertices** to ensure no two vertices are further apart than the given threshold (the definition of a *segment* is *a geometry part between two vertices*)!

To obtain individual geometries representing parts of your 'segments' with a max. length, you'd need to get more involved; there is no simple command as of yet.

There are multiple possibilities, e.g.:

- create line 'segments' from the densified lines (following the usage of `ST_Segmentize` above); you'd get 'segments' with arbitrary lines not longer than the threshold given to `ST_Segmentize`.
- create line 'segments' of fixed length, using `ST_LineSubstring`; well defined line length, e.g. you could find a length that divides a line equally

For your case (initial two-vertice 'segments' will have segments with *exactly* 50m length, except the last one with *up to* 50m length), the first approach should work just fine:

```
WITH
  densified AS (
    SELECT <id>, -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id
           ST_AsText(ST_Segmentize(geom, 50)) AS geom
    FROM   public.segments
  )

SELECT id AS line_id,
       path[1] AS segment_id,
       geom
FROM   (
  SELECT d.id,
         dmp.path,
         ST_MakeLine(dmp.geom, LEAD(dmp.geom) OVER(PARTITION BY d.id ORDER BY dmp.path)) AS geom
  FROM   densified AS d,
         LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(d.geom) AS dmp
) q
WHERE  geom IS NOT NULL
;
```

Don't forget to replace `<id>` with the actual *id* column of your table, or use the commented out `ROW_NUMBER`

Note that I *do not* use a cast to `GEOGRAPHY`, since your mentioned CRS is a metric projection already.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using British National Grid (27700). If I put 'geom:GEOMETRY' it seems to work fine. There are two aspects I'd like to ask: a) The geom column created is text type, what do I need to do to make it of Geometry type?  b) If ST_Segmentize only insterts vertices. What would be then the command to obtain the actual subsegments?

Comment: Sorry, ignore first question. I just need to remove 'ST_AsText' from the query. I'd appreciate any tip on the 2nd one.

Comment: @PitrakoJunior see update

Comment: @PitrakoJunior btw., I referred to `::GEOGRAPHY`, not `::GEOMETRY`; it's a `GEOMETRY` already; read about those two type in the docs. the unit of that CRS is metre already, so no need for any cast at all!

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Thanks for the script. I must admit I understand very little of it. I'll have to spend some time reading some tutorials. I was aware you had used GEOGRAPHY, it was just giving me a lot of warnings. I changed to GEOMETRY since I have projected coordinates, and then it worked fine. I'll read about it anyway.

Comment: I have just seen your update. So no need to cast at all to GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY

Comment: what is the difference between segment id and line id? why have both? Neither are unique ids